# Recover from a Lost Drupal Administration Menu

Tags: rules

When I log into the Admin on my site, the drupal controls are all missing.  Our former Web Developers refered me to an article online that told me I need to enable the toolbars by:

What you need to do is access the main "Modules" page. The best way to get there is by typing in the URL of the modules page.

Try adding one of these to your main domain name:
•/admin/modules/
•?q=admin/modules

Neither of these worked. With /admin/modules/ I get "Page Not Found".

With ?q=admin/modules I get "Access Denied"

How can I get the drupal controls back so I can make edits?

Answer (score 0):

Open below URL and change settings

admin/people/permissions

Or else you can edit here roles & permissions

admin/people/permissions/roles

Comment: Didn't work.  I got "Access Denied"

Comment: If you use Devel Module than load user and edit access

$a = user_load(1);
dpm($a);

Answer (score 0):

If you use "Devel" Module than load user and edit access

```
$a = user_load(1);
dpm($a);
```